# A nested SingleChildScrollView automatically scrolls down when its parent ListView.builder is scrolled

Tags: flutter, dart

----- Edited -----

I found giving PageStorageKey to its parent widget class somehow makes it share/remember the positions of multiple SingleChildScrollView widgets inside. After deleting the PageStorageKey, the following symptom is gone.

---

I have a code structure that can be simplified as below.

```dart
ListView.builder
  SizedBox
    Card
      Flexible
        SingleChildScrollView
```

[image]

What happens is when the content of `SingleChildScrollView` is bigger than its parent widget (so scrolling may be enabled) it appears as automatically scrolled down in a new (newly loading or refreshed) card item if the `ListView.builder` is scrolled manually.

I tried many ways including the ones ChatGPT suggested but failed.

Simply putting `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to `SingleChildScrollView` is not the solution as I will allow manual scrolling.

Comment: Could you please share the code of it so that the errorr can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `SinglechildScrollView` inside `ListView.builder` because it is already scrollable.

Therefore you can remove the `SinglechildScrollView` from it.

Comment: The SinglechildScrollView is in each card item of ListView.builder so each card can contain contents bigger than the card itself.